# Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated in phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am using `class.phpmailer.php` to send email from my local server, it's processing well in my local server with PHP version `php5.3.4` but after I update PHP version to `5.5.4` it's showing the following message:

```
Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead in class.phpmailer.php`
```

This is the line causing the error:

```
$encoded = preg_replace('/([\000-\011\013\014\016-\037\075\077\137\177-\377])/e', "'='.sprintf('%02X', ord(stripslashes('\\1')))", $encoded);
```

Comment: The error is pretty straightforward having in mind the differences in PHP versions. It means that certain feature is deprecated in this versions. In this case - the `/e` modifier. As well as a suggestion what function to use is provided in the error message.

Comment: Updating PHPMailer would solve the issue. It was a [reported bug](http://sourceforge.net/p/phpmailer/bugs/341/) which has been fixed.

Comment: @ljacqu urgh, sourceforge :(

Comment: Thank all, Now i can fixed by @ljacqu told me to remove `e`

Comment: The sourceforge project is long dead; PHPMailer is now [on Github](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Answer (score 14):

Try and Replace:

This

```
$encoded = preg_replace('/([\000-\011\013\014\016-\037\075\077\137\177-\377])/e',"'='.sprintf('%02X', ord(stripslashes('\\1')))", $encoded);
```

With

```
$encoded = preg_replace_callback('/([\000-\011\013\014\016-\037\075\077\137\177-\377])/',function($m) { return '='.sprintf('%02X', ord(stripslashes($m[1]))); }, $encoded);
```

Comment: Don't bother, just update PHPMailer to a recent version.

Comment: My original line doesn't call "stripslashes", but still worked! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
switch (strtolower($position)) {
  case 'phrase':
    //$encoded = preg_replace("/([^A-Za-z0-9!*+\/ -])/e", "'='.sprintf('%02X', ord('\\1'))", $encoded);
    $encoded = preg_replace_callback("/([^A-Za-z0-9!*+\/ -])/e",function($m) { return '='.sprintf('%02X', ord(stripslashes($m[1]))); }, $encoded);
    break;
  case 'comment':
    //$encoded = preg_replace("/([\(\)\"])/e", "'='.sprintf('%02X', ord('\\1'))", $encoded);
    $encoded = preg_replace_callback("/([\(\)\"])/e",function($m) { return '='.sprintf('%02X', ord(stripslashes($m[1]))); }, $encoded);
  case 'text':
  default:
    // Replace every high ascii, control =, ? and _ characters
    //TODO using /e (equivalent to eval()) is probably not a good idea
    //$encoded = preg_replace('/([\000-\011\013\014\016-\037\075\077\137\177-\377])/e',"'='.sprintf('%02X', ord('\\1'))", $encoded);
    $encoded = preg_replace_callback('/([\000-\011\013\014\016-\037\075\077\137\177-\377])/',function($m) { return '='.sprintf('%02X', ord(stripslashes($m[1]))); }, $encoded);
    break;
}
```

yes. it's work on php 7.2.

Comment: It works, but should remove the `e` modifier or could get this error: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37559717/3255692)