# Warning: preg_replace_callback(): Modifier /e cannot be used with replacement callback

Tags: php

I have a problem with php 5.5: when i use this code:

```
$source = preg_replace('/&#(\d+);/me', "utf8_encode(chr(\\1))", $source);
$source = preg_replace('/&#x([a-f0-9]+);/mei', "utf8_encode(chr(0x\\1))", $source);
```

return error

> Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead

I use with preg_replace_callback:

```
$source = preg_replace_callback('/&#(\d+);/me', function($m) { return utf8_encode(chr($m[1])); },$source);
$source = preg_replace_callback('/&#x([a-f0-9]+);/mei', function($m) { return utf8_encode(chr("0x".$m[1])); },$source);
```

it return warning:

> Warning: preg_replace_callback(): Modifier /e cannot be used with replacement callback

What would be the correct code for achieving this?

Comment: The issue is with that `e` `(modifier)` that you were using within your `regex` pattern along with `preg_replace_callback()` function.Remove that `e` `(modifier)` from your regex.  So simply your code looks like as  `preg_replace_callback('/&#(\d+);/m', function($m) { return utf8_encode(chr($m[1])); },$source);`

Comment: thanks for your support, it's worked.

Answer (score 3):

*[Narendrasingh Sisodia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2899618/narendrasingh-sisodia) posted the below as a comment; it should have been an answer, so I am adding it here as Community Wiki:*

The issue is with that `e` (modifier) that you were using within your regex pattern along with `preg_replace_callback()` function. Remove that `e` (modifier) from your regex.

So simply your code looks like:

```
preg_replace_callback('/&#(\d+);/m', function($m) { return utf8_encode(chr($m[1])); },$source);
```