# How can i hide PHPMailer warning messages

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have trouble with PHPmailer class. When I click to submit button then the warning message appears:

> Warning: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is no longer supported, use preg_replace_callback instead in D:\LocalHost\htdocs...\class.phpmailer.php on line 1216*
>
> Message Successfully sent.

How can I hide these messages

Comment: _"use preg_replace_callback instead"_

Comment: open the PHP file and remove the ` /e modifier` or add `error_reporting(~E_WARNING)`

Comment: if that's the real phpmailer, upgrade it, your using a very old version https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: The use of the `/e` modifier was removed from PHPMailer many years ago - that means you're using a very old, obsolete, buggy and vulnerable version. [Update it now](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). Your app, server, and data are at risk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd be best off updating PHPMailer, but there are a couple ways to hide this.

**A Possible Fix Depending on Your Version:**

[Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated in phpmailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24926186/deprecated-preg-replace-the-e-modifier-is-deprecated-in-phpmailer)

One is to disable displaying the errors globaly by adding this in to your code:

```
error_reporting(0);
```

That will disable **all** errors, which might be undesired, so you can also try to suppress only warnings with:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_WARNING);
```

And lastly, you might be able to disable it by adding a `@` in front of the preg_replace command:

```
$var = @preg_replace(...
```

Comment: @YMG You're welcome, if this fixed it, please select this a the answer.

Comment: @YMG thats a real bad fix, its sticking your head in the sand

Comment: @Exit updateing is one option, editing the exiting version the OP has is another

Comment: @rtfm What was the question? This: "How can i hide these messages". I answered the question asked by the original poster. You've taken offense that I didn't do it according to your wishes, yet have posted no answer yourself and voted my answer down out of spite.

Comment: not my vote. and really its a classic XY problem. the OP does not know that  simply hiding errors is a bad idea

Comment: Hence: "You'd be best off updating PHPMailer".

Comment: I find suppressing warnings with @ is sometimes necessary.  I'm not going to downvote this answer.  It answers the question. :-/

Comment: @DataHerder i think you will have a hard time convincing many developers that suppressing warnings\errors is ever a good idea let alone necessary

Comment: s/sometimes/virtually never/

Comment: Nobody accidentally uses the /e modifier, so simply ignoring the warning almost certainly means that you've now got some broken functionality. @YMG, check the content of your emails on the recipient's side, you will likely notice errors. (Like placeholder tags that haven't been filled in.)

Comment: @rtfm I would agree.  But if you're dealing with some kind of legacy code and you don't have time to refactor?  Put an @ sign because it's messing up your view from time to time, it's far and few between when I would actually do that.  Personally I always have warnings on, I would never say to actually suppress warnings all the time, that can cause some really strange bugs that I myself have had the *wonderful* time debugging.  This post answers the question though.  I'm not so sure why people are all up and arms about it.

Comment: I guess this answer is missing what you want... an *ought*.

Comment: Listen, there are all sorts of levels of best practices. And there are people running servers with PHP 5.3. Some people just want to get rid of the problem as fast as possible and worry about it later. Whatever, it's their call. Yes, fixing the problem is **definitely** the right thing to do, but they asked for a specific solution. Maybe it is a temporary fix for now, and they plan to do a revamp later. Maybe the site is temporary itself. I still can't get over how much has been said here rather than providing an answer with an "acceptable solution".

Comment: Alright, everyone can stop complaining. I posted a link to a duplicate question with a potential fix.